# Steps for Instantiating a BufferedImage

Tags: java, instantiation, bufferedimage

I've been researching the `BufferedImage` class to use for game programming purposes (so that I can make image maps for levels and use `getRGB()` to identify the tile in each pixel), but I'm very confused about how to actually make a `BufferedImage`. What's got me particularly confused is how you can't make a `BufferedImage` using an `Image` as a parameter. Step by step, how does one instantiate a `BufferedImage` for a simple image file (e.g. a .jpg)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple steps - `ImageIO.read(File file)` as shown in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.File%29)

Comment: Thanks.  I was reading the Image documentation but didn't find the ImageIO documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can load an image with `ImageIO.read(new File("example.jpg"));`